# Centering Flexbox content without overlapping Navigation

Tags: html, css, iframe, flexbox

I'm trying to center a video in the main body of my page. I have a navigation at the top of the page and a footer at the bottom which contains some information about the video itself.

What I want to do is make it so that the video is always centered, but also make sure that the navigation and footer never overlap the video when resized. Here is the code I have at present:

```css
.Site {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
}
.Site-content {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.Site-header,
.Site-footer {
  flex: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 600;
  height: 10vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
.Site-header {
  top: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
.Site-footer {
  bottom: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid red;
}
.video-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 70%;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.video-container iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body class="Site">
  <div class="Site-header">This is a header</div>
  <div class="Site-content">
    <div class="video-container">
      <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/100978843" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="Site-footer">This is the footer</div>
</body>
```

I've tried changing the `header` and `footer` by removing `position: absolute` but that seems to break the flexbox centering.

How would I go about amending this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need absolute/relative position here you can use `justify-content: space-between` with `flex-direction: column`, harder part is keeping `iframe` responsive but you can do something like this

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.Site {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.Site-header {
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
}
.Site-footer {
  border-top: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
}
iframe {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 70vh;
}
```

```html
<body class="Site">
  <div class="Site-header">This is a header</div>
  <div class="Site-content">
    <div class="video-container">
      <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/100978843" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="Site-footer">This is the footer</div>
</body>
```